# Web App manifest: Setting of the default orientation is ignored

Tags: android, web-applications, screen-orientation

I am trying to set the default orientation of a Web App using the following manifest JSON-file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.9",
  "short_name": "My Web App",
  "name": "My Web App in Portrait Mode",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/homescreen-icon.png",
      "sizes": "196x196",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/index.php",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "theme_color": "#5a8238",
  "background_color": "#1a2a08"
}
```

Using Chromes developer tools I can check if the manifest has loaded correctly and all looks fine: Orientation is set to `portrait` (and Display to `fullscreen`).

But adding the web app to the homescreen on mobile Chrome and then open it from there, I can still view the Web App in landscape.

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out that the `orientation` attribut only works if `display` set to `standalone`:

```
{
  …
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  …
}
```